# How to filter events generated programmatically?

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox, itemlistener

I want to log 'user activity'. I am struggling to log **user-fired event** that selected value of combo box was changed (by the user, not by application calling `combo.setSelectedItem()` or similar stuff).

Here is what I did so far: I registered an `ItemListener` for a `JComboBox`

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            log(USER_SELECTED_ITEM, e);
        }
    }
});
```

However, the `itemStateChanged(...)` is called even if the combo box value is selected programmatically by `comboBox.setSelectedItem(...)`.

I also found a boolean field, `AWTEvent.isSystemGenerated`, which I hoped is `true` when event is generated by explicit call of `comboBox.setSelectedItem(...)`.

```
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
        if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            boolean sysGen = AWTAccessor.getAWTEventAccessor().isSystemGenerated(e);
            System.out.println("system generated: " + sysGen);
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, `true` is never printed out.

How can I filter out events which are generated programmatically?

Comment: your code calls `comboBox.setSelectedItem(...)`?

Comment: `getSource()` might be useful to you

Comment: No, it's a third party code which I can't modify. I event don't have any sources of that code...

Comment: in your listener print both kinds of events and see how they differ

Comment: Attributes of 'user generated' and 'programatically generated' events are the same - I'm unable to distinguish them this way.

Comment: can you post here how they both look? you might think the way of mouse listener if there was a click and location was near by to the JComboBox then it should be user-generated.

Comment: You should wonder why you would want to distinguish between user-selection and programmatic selection. Why aren't they suppose to do the same

Comment: ``event01.toString().equals(event02.toString())`` returns ``true``. However now I noticed private fields of ``AWTEvent`` called ``isPosted`` and ``isSystemGenerated``. Maybe that's the way...

Comment: yes, now I found it too. How you would access it?

Comment: +1 for Robin's comment. Perhaps if you explained your problem in more detail, then we might be able to offer a different approach.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following method `getItemSelectable()` *It returns the originator of the event.* [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/event/ItemEvent.html#getItemSelectable%28%29)

```
ItemSelectable itemOrginator = e.getItemSelectable()
```

**itemOrginator** is the object source of the event.

and check both cases the `int userOriginType` and `int progOriginType` using `getID`method inherited from `java.awt.AWTEvent` class.

Comment: ``e.getItemSelectable()`` returns the same object as ``e.getSource()``. This is not what I was asking for. And where are your ``userOrigin`` and ``progOrigin`` integers from? The ``e.getId()`` method returns an event type (see javadoc) and not the origin of event.

Comment: did you checked if the both values are different or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Its simple. Define a golbal variable fromSystem.

```
comboBox.addItemListener(new ItemListener() 
{
   @Override
   public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) 
   {
      if (e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) 
      {
           if(!fromSystem)
           {
               log(USER_SELECTED_ITEM, e);
           }
      }
   }
```

});

Now where ever you have written comboBox.setSelectedItem(...) replace this line with below 3 lines.

```
fromSystem = true;
comboBox.setSelectedItem(...);
fromSystem = false
```

Got it??